# Possible to change width of table to 100% with jQuery when width is hard coded in table?

Tags: jquery, iframe, html-table, width

I'm working on a site that is framing in some content via an iFrame.  The framed in content is  sitting in a table with a static width applied to it.  The table has no class or ID.  Is there anyway I can get the width changed to 100% with jQuery?  Again, I have no access to this table, it's being framed in.

Here is the table in question:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width='800'>
```

It's being framed in like this:

```
<iframe src="URL TO CONTENT" width="900" height="1500" style="margin:10px 0 10px 10px;"></iframe>
```

I can't think of anyway to get this to work?  Anyone have any ideas how to change the table width to 100%?

Comment: Is the iframe `src` the same domain as the page it's included from?

Comment: The SRC points to an outside domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access DOM on an iframe if it is in an external domain.

Comment: I thought that was probably the case.  Thanks.